# multi thread timer in the spring framework

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, timer

The feature of automatically removing items from the shopping cart if a member does not proceed with payment within 30 minutes before purchasing a product in e-commerce.
Multi thread timer is not work on the concurrent situations. if timer is over 8 counts, windows pc(i5 intel) became pending state. it is not response from on the mouse click. After timer is done, pc become normal state.
**How can i increase multi thread timer count ?**

```
public class CommonController {
    private DemoService demoService;
  
    @Autowired
    public CommonController(DemoService demoService) {
      this.demoService = demoService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/requestAjax.do"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public void requestAjax(HttpServletRequest request) {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {   
            demoService.doCheckTime();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        }
    }
}

@Service
public class serviceImpl {

    @Async
    public void doCheckTime() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        int delay = 10; // 10분
    
        MultiThreadTimer multiThreadTimer = new MultiThreadTimer();
        String result = multiThreadTimer.StartTimer(delay);
        if(result.equals("0000"))
            System.out.println("special working run.");
    }
}

@Service
public class MultiThreadTimer {

    @Async
    public String StartTimer(int delay) {
        //  private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        //  private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(64);
        //  private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(64);

        final CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>(); // future 변수를 final로 선언
        try {
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                ScheduledExecutorService timerExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

                ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = timerExecutor.schedule(() -> {
                    System.out.println("end of timer!");
                    timerExecutor.shutdown(); // 타이머 Executor 종료
                    future.complete(null); // 외부 변수 변경
                }, delay, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

                // 타이머 Executor 종료
                timerExecutor.shutdown();
            });

            // CompletableFuture가 완료될 때까지 대기
            future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        String result = "0000";
        return result;
    }
}
```